# Equivalence of LOOP (primitive recursive functions) and of SRL (reversible transformations) programs

Tags: computability-theory

This is a question about the decidability of program equivalence.

Primitive recursive functions correspond exactly to the functions
that can be implemented on a specific register machine usually
named LOOP, see for instance [1].

It is known that the equivalence of LOOP programs is undecidable.
The problem is: are two given LOOP programs P and Q equivalent? (i.e.
 do they implement the same function?)

The interest in reversible (and total) transformations lead to
the development of another LOOP-like register language, named SRL
(simple register language) whose programs are bijections Z^k --> Z^k,
see [2].

One SRL program (with k=2) is

> (a)    for x {inc y}
>          inc x

This program implements the bijection

```
x' = x+1
y' = x+y
```

where x' and y' are the final values of x and y respectively.

(Most LOOP programs are not bijections because of two reasons:
   - Projection (all registers except one are ignored), say f(x,y)=x
   - dec x (if x'=0 (after), we can not go backwards; 
     before the execution it could be x=0 or x=1.

Now, the definition of SRL, it is very simple.

Domain: Z={...,-1,0,1,2,...}.

The input and the output are all the (initial and final respectively) values
of the registers used by the program.

```
  instruction         effect

  inc x               increment x by one

  dec x               decrement x by one

  for x {P}           execute x times the SRL program P
                      P can not have "inc x" or "dec x" instructions
                      The value of x is not changed.
                      P is executed x times ("controlled composition")
  P;Q                 Concatenation of two instructions (composition)
```

(The inverse of "inc x" is "dec x", the inverse of "for x{P}"
 is "for x {P^{-1}}", the inverse of "P;Q" is "Q^{-1};P^{-1}")

Another SRL program (n,a,b)-> (n',a',b') is

> (b)    for n{for a{inc b}; for b{inc a}}

The outputs a and b are exponentional (on the input values), they
are related to the Fibonacci sequence.

My question is

> > > Is the SRL-EQUIVALENCE decision problem decidable?
> > >       I've been thinking about that for some time, but I don't know the answer.

Problem: are two given SRL programs P and Q equivalent? (i.e.
 do they implement the same function?)

References

[1] Meyer and Ritchie, The complexity of loop programs,
        IBM Watson Research Center, Yorktown Heights

[2] Armando Matos, "Analysis of a simple reversible language", 
        Theoretical Computer Science